# In MFC Edit Control, calling SetWindowText in EN_UPDATE event handler makes ctrl+z functionality not working?

Tags: c++, mfc

In MFC edit control I need to allow only 0 to 2147483647. For that if user tries to type value more than 2147483647, I need to reset the value to previously entered good value.

To handle this requirement I am calling `SetWindowText` in `EN_UPDATE` event handler which makes <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (undo) functionality is not working?

I tried `ReplaceSel` function instead of `SetWindowText` that is also not helped in making <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (undo) functionality working.

```
SetSel( 0, -1, true );
ReplaceSel( m_szGoodValue, true);
```

Please help me to make undo/redo functionality working

Comment: What you're trying to do is both complex as well as produces a poor user experience. What you should be doing instead is validating user input and giving visual feedback (such as coloring the background or displaying an icon next to the control), and dis-/enable the submit button in response. MFC also has [dialog data validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-validation) built in, if that is something you wish to explore.

Comment: When you add your variable you should be able to provide a min / max value in the wizard that will validate this and it will then be automatic. Whenever you call `UpdateData` to save and **validate** the values it does the work.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle I dont want error or warning message thrown by DDV_MinMaxLong. How to avoid it

Comment: Override UpdateData as it is virtual and do your own processing perhaps.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Overriding UpdateData is too late, it only gets called once OK is clicked. Best is what IInspectable suggested, that is in EN_UPDATE check if the content of the edit control fulfills whatever requirement and show an error message/icon/grey OK etc.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Gotcha